# c# be able to using the stream, even after change the variable that holding it

Tags: c#, algorithm, variables, stream

is there any way to keep the stream alive and usable, even after changing the variable?

pesudo-code:

```
func send > send
func StreamHandler > handle > close
        
    while (true)
        stream = null
        loop 5:
            stream = new stream
            send(stream)
        StreamHandler(stream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use the stream after overwriting the varaible, but you can use a collection of streams to store them all.

[C# List of Streams dispose/close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848065/c-sharp-liststream-dispose-close)
Answer by: [mkedobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176647/mkedobbs)